# DELETE query in sequelize.query() method

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to write a delete query in the sequelize.query() method but it is showing me an error stating `"errorMessage": "Internal Server Error"`.

Actually what I am trying to do is that, I want to insert a row into the PostgreSQL table, but if there is a duplication, I was thinking to first delete that entire row and then inserting it again with new values, because I don't want to change just the updated field, rather the complete row.

This is the code of what I am trying to do -

```
const upsertUser = async (userData) => {
    
    return sequelizeInstance.query(
        `
            DELETE FROM user_profiles
            WHERE email = $1;

            INSERT INTO user_profiles
            (email, full_name, gender, phone_no, profession, bio, linkedin, codeforces, leetcode, github)
            VALUES ( $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10 );
        `,
        {
            bind: [
                userData.email,
                userData.full_name,
                userData.gender,
                userData.phone_no,
                userData.profession,
                userData.bio,
                userData.linkedin,
                userData.codeforces,
                userData.leetcode,
                userData.github
            ]
        }
    )
}
```

Is there a way, I could achieve the desired functionality ?

The above SQL query is working fine if I write it directly on pgAdmin, but not with Sequelize.

( I am using Sequelize v6, PostgreSQL v14, and pgAdmin 4 )

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "I don't want to change just the updated field, rather the complete row" - can you explain a bit more about the reason for this?

Comment: Why don't you want to update all fields of the existing record?

Comment: Because the data is to be entered by a user via a form, and I don't know a way to check which and how many field/s has the user updated ? So I was thinking of deleting the whole row and then insert the updated row. And also email here is my primary key, therefore I would only be deleting a single row and then updating it.